# How to share Image + Text + URL via WhatsApp in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to share text,image and URL via WhatsApp.

I have looked into few links, but it has only share text feature.

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text here");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Comment: [try this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351563/how-to-share-an-image-with-whatsapp-android/31470300#31470300

you can use it for image and text both.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Intent Intent = new Intent();
   Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
     Intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, picture_text);
    Intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
   Intent.setType("image/jpeg");
   Intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        startActivity(Intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp not installed.");
    }
```